# Approving item makes no new version

Tags: version-history, content-approval

In my SharePoint list I have item that I have just approved. I clicked the `Approve/Decline` button in Edit form, and then chose `Approved`.

Now when I take a look at `Version history`, I see that last change was made by me, and with correct time, but version number is still `1.0`. Is this behavior correct? How can I change this?

My list has both versioning and moderation enabled. From my `elements.xml` in List Definition:

```
<ListTemplate
    VersioningEnabled="TRUE"
    EnableModeration="True"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dazzles me a little, it seems you did enable Approval however you get still the version 1.0. Are you sure that versioning is enabled?

If you only enable Major, then every Check In and Approve will move to 1.0, 2.0, etc.
if you enabled Minor (that is Drafts) then Deepu's explanation is absolutely valid

- Check-In - Minor would increase/overwrite Minor
- ChecIn-Major - would move it to Pending if Content Approval is enabled (with or without Workflow being enabled), once approved, the Draft will disappear (promoted if you want).

Hope if helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: I have Versioning enabled. I posted snippet from my ListDefinition.

Comment: So if you repeatedly CheckOut/Check-In and Approve and look at the Version History, or add the Version colum your view still shows as 1.0? Also use VersioningEnabled="TRUE" and EnableMinorVersions= “True” BOTH!

Comment: Exactly. The "Last modified at... by" date and user changes, but Version is still 1.0

Comment: Go into List/Library Settings, validate under Versioning Settings that Versioning is really enabled. Without it, the behaviour you experience would make sense, otherwise something is fishy!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the default behaviour. When a list item is enabled with versioning in SharePoint, you have an option to publish it as a major or minor version. Once the item is published as a major version, the item status changes from "draft" to "Pending".

Now, once the "Pending" document is approved or rejected, there would not be any changes to the version. It just changes the modified by to the person who has approved the document.

To overcome this, you should either stop using the default content approval workflow or start tracking the person modified, by capturing that in a different column.

Comment: OK, but is it possible to change the default behavior? I would need to track, who and when approves or rejects items.

Comment: Track or Control? Besides enabling Content Approval and Versioning - these enable Control, your could also enable Alerts on Changes with daily Digest - this shall report on every single change.

Comment: There are workarounds. Whats missing is the person who has modified the document, just before the approval. You can track the modified person by writing an item updating event receiver and save this detail into another column. If you are thinking about a codeless solution, why not trying the same with SharePoint designer workflow. Here you will be able to save the approver details in separate columns of your own and you have much more options.